# Alignment issue with flexbox in css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to align menu on the left side and page content which has multiple dashboard panels/cards on the right side. The problem is dashboard panels/cards are dynamic sometimes number of cards might be 1 and sometimes more than 1. I want all the dashboard panels on the right side to be center aligned.

I tried with the following code but its not working as expected:

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

aside {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.flex-items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  margin-left: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  flex: 1;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside>Menu</aside>
  <section class="flex-items">
    <div class="flex-item">item1</div>
    <div class="flex-item">item2</div>
    <div class="flex-item">item3</div>
  </section>
</main>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/prbYmB)

Finally, I would like to have all the items to be responsive when page is shrunk.

Comment: Move `flex: 1` from `.flex-item` to `.flex-items`.

Comment: Do you right items to be aligned in column or in row? Regading centering, centered vertically or horizontally?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov I want items on the right to be centered horizontally. Even If there is single item on the right side it must be centered horizontally.

Comment: @user1188867 Items should align in row or in column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the `flex: 1;` attribute from `.flex-item` as it looks like you wanted them to be a specific size. `width` and `flex` don't make sense used together as `flex: 1;` enables `flex-grow` and that tells the div to use all available space.
I then added `flex-grow: 1;` to `.flex-items` so it uses all the available space (before it was just as wide as it needed to be) so the `justify-content: center` can do it's work.

```css
main {
  display:flex;
} 

aside {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:2px solid red;
}

.flex-items {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.flex-item {
  margin-left:10px;
  border:2px solid red;
  width:80px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside>Menu</aside>
  <section class="flex-items">
  <div class="flex-item">item1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">item2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">item3</div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Note: I changed the widths and margins to allow better rendering in small spaces